# I am Using mongodb in rails and when use the carrierwave gem this thrown errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the following commond

> gem 'carrierwave'
>
> bundle
>
> rails generate uploader image
>
> mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

but it gives the errors

> NoMethodError in PostsController#index
>
> undefined method `mount_uploader' for Post:Class Extracted source
>   (around line #8):
>
> `line #8:  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`
>
> end

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are using the wrong gem, for mongodb using mongoid ORM you should use the following gem,

```
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
```

If you install this you problem should get solved.